# Github, why does my python code have ^M and no new lines?

Tags: python, github

The code in my editor shows up fine but whenever I push it to Github it's just being displayed in one line, I have never had this issue before, could this be `python` related?

[code in github](https://github.com/midrizi/statistics-and-file-comparison/blob/master/main.py)

**Edit:** When the file is viewed as raw it seems to be fine.

Comment: Strange line separator

Comment: what editor do you use ? Did you push your code through the editor or through CLI?

Comment: Some kind of setting must be screwed up. Have you checked out [Configuring Git to handle line endings](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings)?

Comment: @Vlakius I use PyCharm and yes though CLI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You editor is using a CR (carriage-return). That's the ^M you see in Github. This is a Windows application way of marking a new line, rather than the Linux `\n` newline. It is somewhat surprising that this isn't a `\r\n` (so you would see new lines, but all lines ending with `^M`) since that what Windows stuff usually does - your editor seems to only put in `\r`, which Linux just ignores and that's what Github is using to display your file.

The raw file is handled by the browser which knows how to handle `\r`, hence, it looks right.

To fix this use a search and replace from `\r` to `\n` in an editor capable of it. You should probably configure your editor to use `\n`, or switch editor.

Comment: isn't `\r` only what was/is standard for mac ?

Comment: @hl037_ I'm not familiar enough, but a cursory search seems to indicate `\n` is the standard, which matches with it being a unix system.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/439440/did-mac-os-lion-switch-to-using-line-feeds-lf-n-for-line-breaks-instead-of

Comment: Indeed, the first answer there says it's been a very long time since macs used \r. It has been been posix compliant for a long while.